# How to convert long value of date object to date

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date, datetime

I have long value of date object that has been converted by `java long` from `date` object and now i want to use that long value in `SQL` query to be compare with date.

I want to convert long value to `SQL` date object because I want to fetch data by date filter

I tried like

```
"select DATEADD(SECOND, 1376773200000/1000 ,'1970/1/1')"
```

but it won't work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use parameterized SQL instead, which will allow you to specify the value as a `java.sql.Date` instead. For example:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE CreatedDate > ?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(timestampValue));
```

(Or use `java.sql.Timestamp` - it depends on the exact type of your field.)

Comment: thanks but i have already used criteria and now i altering that one only. is it possible to use in criteria?

Comment: @KeyurArdeshana: Do you mean you're using Hibernate? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: yes, actually i have criteria and to add restriction on map i am using sqlRestriction so in that only sql query is valid so i am talking about sql to compare date and field i want to compare have long value of date.

Comment: @KeyurArdeshana: Why are you using SqlRestriction rather than (say) `Restrictions.ge`? That's the idiomatic way of writing a "greater than" restriction in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

A good post is [How do I add Hours, mins, seconds to dateadd sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199379/how-do-i-add-hours-mins-seconds-to-dateadd-sql)

In oracle, you could do it like:

```
declare
 vdate      date;
 vseconds number;
begin
  vseconds := 5;
  vdate      := to_date('2.1.2010 05:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
  vdate := vdate + vseconds/24/60/60;
end;
```

which is equivalent to `select to_date('2.1.2010 05:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') + 5/24/60/60 from dual;`

Another example found herehttp://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566542/Date-and-Time-Data-Types-and-Functions-SQL-Server#27:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1, @date) AS 'Second' ; @date is a variable.
```

Converting long to date:

If the long date is 1220227200L , then date is

```
Date d = new Date(1220227200L * 1000);
```

Output

```
Sun Aug 31 20:00:00 GMT-04:00 2008
```

Comment: instead of 2.1.2010 05:00, i have long value of this date and this make really tough...

Comment: I have added code to get date from long. You could easily format the date value using SimpleDateFormatter.

Comment: same thing i want in sql server 2008. i am using hibernate but no scope without use of sql as i want to add restriction on map and this is not possible

Comment: DATEADD is standard SQL, it should work for SQL server as will as Oracle.